# About input to a javascript class method call that's exported via exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, extendscript

The question here pertains to ExtendScript code, but I believe it should be agnostic to any javascript implementation.

If we have something like this in a JS library file (base64.js)

```
exports.encode64 = encoder('+/');
//...
function encoder(extra) {
//...
}
```

and then in another file that uses the exported method, that first imports/includes/requires base64.js somewhere

```
var data = "some data";
base64.encode64(data);
```

does that mean if we were not to export the method and directly call encoder(), assuming that base64.js is "included" into the global namespace where code is executed, then we would call it like this?

```
encoder('+/' + data);
```

So far the exports I've seen typically export a method with no arguments assigning an alias to a function/method exposed outside of the library/file. But this case here is strange to me since we pass in argument, and later we also pass in argument when calling the alias.

If my assumption is incorrect, then what is the proper usage of encoder that would match base64.encode64 alias to it?

For reference/context the full source code to base64.js can be found here:

https://github.com/debrouwere/Extendables/blob/master/dependencies/base64.js

On a related note, is there some good tutorial that explains about all this variation of exports and require/import/include?

Comment: From looking at the source, `encoder` returns a function itself to allow the library author to expose two different versions of an otherwise identical function. You are correct that he could refactor the inner method (declared on line 18) into an exported method and accept `extra` as s second parameter, although the chosen approach is a friendlier interface to the user of the library. To answer your "how to call" Q. If you got encoder directly (though it is not actually exported), you would call it like: `var myStr = (encoder('+/`))(data)` - I added an unnecessary pair parens for clarity.

Comment: Thanks, helpful explanation. I overlooked the details of encoder() that it returns a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with how exports work. For now, assume that exports work the way you believe it to work without the funny `encoder('+/')` business. In other words, exports simply exports javascript objects (functions, objects, arrays etc.) in a simple way without inventing additional syntax. Assume that line looks like this:

```
function encode64 (data) { /* ... */ );
exports.encode64 = encode64;
```

because that's simply what it's doing. Honest. There's nothing funny going on here.

---

Now lets discuss `encoder()`.

You will notice that the author of that library didn't write the definition of the `encode64()` function anywhere in the source code. Instead, he lets another function, `encoder()`, write the `encode64()` function for him.

The `encoder()` function probably looks something like this:

```
function encoder (extra) {
    // do some stuff
    return function (data) {
        // actual implementation of the encoding function
    }
}
```

So `encoder()` is not the encoding function. It does however return the encoding function (it "writes" it for you):

```
var encode64 = encoder('+/');
// encode64 is a function
```

So the library simply exports the (unnamed) `encode64` function, not `encoder`.

---

So to clarify:

> would call it like this?
>      encoder('+/' + data);

**No**. It calls it like this:

```
var encode64 = encoder('+/');
encode64(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, I find Barry Johnson's comment more informative. But yours adds to that, and your example of how to call it is more intuitive to the user.